# How to show high usage user's username with the top command, if the username is too long?

Tags: linux, top, command, usage, user-accounts

I'm having problem identifying high usage users on a shared Linux machine.

I use the "top" command and it does show which commands are using the most CPU.

But the usernames on this server all start with the same prefix. So the USER column cuts-off  the username right after the prefix.

Is there a convenient way to show which user is using the most CPU resources?

Answer (score 1):

The top program has columns of information that can be added and removed while running by pressing 'f'. There is a column that will display the numeric user id 'd', which may be more useful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ps command to see what processes and user is using the most CPU resources :

`ps aux --sort pcpu`